# Is is posiible to display Editable Row with selected Column wise sorting in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008

I am not sure whether am asking right question or not but here a case where i have to edit row/cells depending on some conditions, ie
I have open **MS SQL Server Management Studio**, right click on tableName and select **Edit Top Row** , it displays editable window where i can edit cell values and
and at the end  click `Execute SQl` so the records get updated.

I want to know whether is possible to dispaly editable window with a particular column sorting

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, it's a bit fiddly, but what you have to do is this:

Right click on your table and select "Edit top 200 rows"
In the results screen, right click and select "Pane" -> "SQL"

You will then see the SQL command that is being executed to see the top 200 results as well as the editable pane.

Edit the SQL to add your order by clause (or whatever you want to see in the edit pane)
In the SQL pane right click and select "Execute SQL"

You will see the editable pane now updates to reflect your query.

When you edit your table, make sure that the editable pane has focus before clicking execute SQL or your results will be lost (easy way to ensure this is to right click in the results pane and click execute SQL from there)